# Is there anyway to extract or save data from an attribute?

Tags: c#, aop, custom-attributes, postsharp

I am starting to work with attributes and for this example the code is written using PostSharp 2.0.

What I would like to do is the method that has the `Stopwatch` attribute or the calling method can access the Elapsed Time.

I am currently writing this codes using C# 4.0

Sample attribute code:

```
[Serializable]
public class StopwatchAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Create new stopwatch
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Begin timing
        stopwatch.Start();

        args.MethodExecutionTag = stopwatch;
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = (Stopwatch)args.MethodExecutionTag;

        // Stop timing
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write result
        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0} ms", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Using the attribute

```
[Stopwatch]
public string Search(string LineNo)
{
    // Search for something
    // Is it possible to know how long (from Stopwatch attribute) Search took 
}

public void CallSearch
{
    string x =  Search("xyz");
    // Is it possible to know how long (from Stopwatch attribute) Search took 
}
```

I get an output of Elapsed time.

However, is there anyway to extend this so that I can send the Elapsed time out.

Ideally I would like to see how long `Search` took from `CallSearch`, but it will be ok if I can even get the result in `Search` itself and then somehow return it.

As a workaround I am currently using ["Hole in the Middle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254881/using-hole-in-the-middle-pattern) pattern.

Thanks

Comment: I had done similar thing using [Unity Interception](http://pnpguidance.net/Post/UnityInterceptionExtensionExampleTransparentProxyPolicyInjectorHandlerAttributeICallHandler.aspx)

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar I am sorry I could not understand how the link your provided does what I am looking for.  Could you please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe attributes are read-only and entirely determined at compile time.  You can't affect attributes after the code is compiled.  Perhaps you could keep a static Dictionary (mapping delegates or MemberInfo to execution time values) to track the last execution time of each method that is marked to track its executon time?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the variables in the attribute will cease to exist after the method ends. In order to do this, you'd need to evaluate the log or some other persistent source for the data. You could write data to a static List or something like this, but there's no code you can write that will reflectively examine the attribute itself to determine how long the last run of the method with that attribute took (unless the attribute class has a method that examines the same persistent store).

The attribute, as you've written, is just a class that is used in a special way by the CLR; it checks for the presence of aspect-oriented attributes, instantiates any as necessary, and calls any handlers as necessary. The class is only in scope while it is needed by the runtime, and once it isn't, it's GCed. To work with an attribute outside the scope of its aspect-oriented purpose, you work with its Type, and/or create a new instance of it using the Activator.

One thing; a Attribute can have static properties. So, you could define a static Stopwatch instance, and set it to the Stopwatch you most recently stopped in OnExit. That would allow you to statically determine the time of the last executed method decorated with the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will try creating a Static property and see if I can work through that.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (sorry, I didn't test it, but the idea must be clear):

```
[Serializable]
public class StopwatchAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Stopwatch stopwatch = null;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var sw = stopwatch ?? new Stopwatch();
        args.MethodExecutionTag = sw; // Better to move this line before .Start
        sw.Start();
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var sw = (Stopwatch) args.MethodExecutionTag;
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0} ms", sw.Elapsed);
    }

    public static Stopwatch Measure(Action action)
    {
        var oldStopwatch = stopwatch;
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        try {
            // !!! Btw, you can measure everything right here.
            action.Invoke();
            return stopwatch;
        }
        finally {
            stopwatch = oldStopwatch;
        }
    }
}
```

Implied usage:

```
[Stopwatch]
public string Search(string LineNo)
{
    // Search for something
    // Is it possible to know how long (from Stopwatch attribute) Search took 
}

public void CallSearch
{
    var stopwatch = StopwatchAttribute.Measure(() => {
        string x =  Search("xyz");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0} ms", stopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

So as you see, PostSharp usage seems not quite necessary here. It can be used for logging such timings, but you must use either similar approach or your own log access API to get logged time.

Comment: Yes this is more or less using the "Hole in the MIddle" pattern.  I am trying to do this with Attributes mainly as a learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes should only be used to add descriptions to classes, properties, and methods at design time that can then be examined at runtime via reflection.

I wouldn't use it to store business logic.

Here is a [great article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/attributes/article.php/c5831) for your reference.